# Verifying the Following Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that the subset of elements of finite order in an Abelian group forms a subgroup. I have shown that it is closed, and that the identity is contained. I am trying to show inverse. I was researching possible hints and I found one, however I am having trouble understanding what it is saying. Can someone explain?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $a$ have finite order, say order $n$. Then $a^n=a(a^{n-1})=e$. Based on this, what is the inverse of $a$? Furthermore, what happens when you raise it to the power $n$ (order of $a$)? What does this say about the order of the inverse?

Comment: so following your hint, we have that $a^n = a(a^{n-1}) = aa^na^{-1}=aa^{-1}=e$ which is only possible if $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of a. thus showing that $a^{-1}$ is in the subset. correct?

Comment: @rover2: Think of $a^{-1}$ *as* $a^{n-1}$. Using that thegroup is abelian, what is $(a^{(n-1)})^n$?

Comment: $(a^{(n-1)})^n = (a^na^{-1})^n = (ea^{-1})^n = (a^{-1})^n = (a^n)^{-1} = e^{-1} =e$

Comment: @rover2: exactly. So the order of the inverse of $a$ is at most $n$ (in fact, divides $n$, but you only need that it is finite).

Comment: do i have to show that the same thing applies for the element $b$?

Comment: @rover2: $b$ is precisely the element $a^{n-1}$, actually.

Comment: how do we know this? sorry i am not seeing it

Comment: $b = a^{-1}$.  That was a given.  $ab = e$.  And $a^{n-1} = a^{-1}$.  You and Clayton figured that out.  So $b = a^{-1} = a^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ and $b$ be inverses.  So $b = a^{-1}$ and $ab =e$.

Suppose $a$ has finite order so that $a^m = e$.  So $a$ is in THE SET.

Is $b$ in THE SET?

Well, $b^m = e*b^m = a^m*b^m = (ab)^m=$ (because the group is Abelian) $= e^m = e$.

So yes $b$ has finite order.

So $b$ is in THE SET.

=========

That is what that snippet is saying.

What that means it that for any element in THE SET, there will be an inverse element in THE SET. So the inverse axiom is satisfied.

.....

And you don't have to prove associativity as that is inherited from the group.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $ab = e$ because $a$ and $b$ are inverses, and that there exists some natural number $m$ such that $a^m = e$ because $a$ has finite order. Now observe that $(ab)^m = (ab)(ab)....(ab)$ m many times, but because $a$ and $b$ are members of an abelian group then we can group all the $a$s together and all the $b$s together, so $(ab)^m = a^mb^m$. Because $a^m = e$, we in fact have that $(ab)^m = b^m$. Recall that $ab = e$ because $a$ and $b$ are inverses, so if we raise both sides to the mth power we have that $(ab)^m = e^m = e$. But we already proved that $(ab)^m = b^m$, hence $b^m = e$. Thus $b$ has finite order.

Comment: how does this show that the inverses are part of the subset?

Comment: Um... if $a$ is in the set then it's inverse $b$ is in the set.  How can that *not* prove inverses are part of the subset?  Would it be easier if we used $a^{-1}$ instead of $b$?  Then $(a^{-1})^ma^m = e$ but $(a^{-1})^ma^m = (a^{-1})^m*e= (a^{-1})^m$.  So $(a^{-1})^m = e$.  So $a^{-1}$ has finite $m$ order.

Comment: The requirement for being part of the subset is that the element has finite order. We have shown that if $b$ is an inverse of an element of finite order then $b$ has finite order, hence $b$ is an element of the subset consisting of all elements of finite order.